# Is it safe to increase transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds on a running Mongod process?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to increase the transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds from 60 seconds to 90 seconds for all the mongo processes in my replica set. this is the command that I'll be using `db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds: 90 } )`.

My questions are -

1. Is it safe to increase transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds while the mongod processes are running and have some pending transactions?
2. Are there any major caveats of increasing the transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds? I read that it increases the cache pressure but I am not sure what's the severity of this. For some context, I have 3 EC2 t2.micro machines where the mongo processes are running and I have some 5 transactions/10 seconds with around 20k documents each.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of transaction lifetime limit is to limit the number of outstanding transactions at any given time and to expire transactions that aren't completed and are just left open.

By raising the limit you will increase resource demands of the database.

Whether that would be a *problem* depends on your specific deployment, query situation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just waned to understand if I should put the value in the mongo's conf file and restart the process or is it okay to change it on a running process when there might be some pending transactions?

Comment: Don't know. I suggest testing.

Comment: Well. It worked out fine changing it on a running instance.